# javafx close window

Tags: user-interface, javafx

I have a javafx app, and I was able to spawn another window, but I can't seem to find a way to close the the window i started in. 
I used this to load the second window

```
var design = Launcher {};

                javafx.stage.Stage
                {
                    title: "Launcher"
                    scene: design.getDesignScene ()
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stage.close(), but you would need a variable that references the original stage.

Comment: thanks, when I get around to tryin it out I'll mark this answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The way it worked for me:

1. I have the Main.fx where I instante the window I want to see first.
   ex:

   var mainWind:MainWindow = MainWindow{ };
2. MainWindow.fx will extend CustomNode and override create() method.
   In the create() method I have the stage
   ex:

   public class MainWindow extends CustomNode{

   ...

   var stage:Stage;

   override function create():Node {

   ```
   var n:Node;
   stage = Stage {
       width: 300
       height: 180
       title: "Login"
       scene: Scene {
           content:[ userText, userTextBox, passwdText, passwdTextBox, btnsBox ]
       }
   }
   return n;
   ```

   }
   }
3. In MainWindow.fx I have a button with an event where I close this stage and show the other one .
   ex:

   Button {

   ```
       text: "Login"
       font:Font{ name:"Arial" size: 12}
       layoutInfo:LayoutInfo {
           width: loginbtn_width
       }
       blocksMouse: false
      //close main window
       onMouseClicked: function(e:MouseEvent):Void { stage.close(); }
      //open the other window
       action: function(){
          // the ConnectionSettings will also extend CustomNode and will have its own stage
           var conSetWind:ConnectionSettings = ConnectionSettings{ };
       }
   ```

   }

Iulia